# How to get the response status code after a camel http call

Tags: apache-camel, camel-http

Hi I am quite new to Camel. I a executing a https4 call from camel route. I want to get the status code for the response. Where can I get this from?

Comment: Do the person with the close vote - why on earth is this unclear? Its a very specific question in apache camel. If you dont understand the framework, please dont throw close votes like this.

Comment: see the section Message headers in the documentation [link](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html)

Comment: Do yourself a favour and start reading the documentation for 5-10 minutes before asking a question here.

Answer (score 13):

Response is located in the Camel's header **CamelHttpResponseCode**.

You can get the value of the header with simple language

```
${header.CamelHttpResponseCode}
```

More details about http4 component are http://camel.apache.org/http4.html

Comment: Where did you see mention of ${header.CamelHttpResponseCode} at that link? As of July 8th, 2019, I see nothing about this header in the documentation you referenced.

Comment: See section "Message Headers" in the above link, the header `Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE` which value is `CamelHttpResponseCode`. Syntax `${}` is Camel Simple language (https://camel.apache.org/simple.html) that is used to fetch info such headers and more.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I just didn't realize that a header named `Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE` would be available named as `CamelHttpResponseCode` with Simple. The HTTP4 docs do not seem to state this explicitly.

Comment: Header name is `CamelHttpResponseCode`, which is defined as a camel constant with variable name `HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE`. Yes confusing at first.